# how do we copy external tables from one schema to another schema in same postgresql database

Tags: sql, postgresql, external-tables

I have two schema's in one database

```
1) public
2) test
```

In public i have list of external tables like

```
ext_table1,ext_table_2,ext_table_3
```

How do i copy those tables to test schema from public in the same database?

Comment: Why "copy" them to begin with? Can't you simply create views in the test schema that select from the external tables in the public schema?

Comment: I am trying to move them to test schema. Once we got them moved, will be dropping the tables from public schema. Goal is not to have any tables under public schema

Comment: What is an 'external' table?  Do you mean foreign table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to move them, then just do that:

```
alter table ext_table1 set schema test;
```

Comment: What if we have 100 tables that needs to move. Could we alter all at once?

Comment: Use PL/pgSQL and dynamic SQL or generate the statements using SQL then use `psql`'s `\gexec` to run the generated SQL. There are tons of examples out there on how you automate things like that